# Que signifie « les si dites » ?

Tags: sens, orthographe

Je suis en train de lire un article scientifique de Sierpinski, *Les exemples effectifs et l'axiome de choix*. Il y a une phrase que je ne comprends pas, je pense que c'est un problème de grammaire. L'OCR du paragraphe en question :

[image: Scan of an article from Sierpinski]

Dans la phrase « Les démonstrations d’existence de ce genre […] » : en anglais, « *The proofs of existence of that sort […]* », que veut dire « les si dites » ? Je présume que cette phrase veut dire, en anglais, « *the ones called pure proofs of existence* ». Mais comme je n'ai jamais vu cette construction je n'en suis pas sûr. Est-ce que ma supposition est correcte ?

Et dans la même phrase, est-ce que c'est un erreur de l'OCR : « ne *nons* donnent pas ordinairement » ? Je ne comprends pas le *nons* et je soupçonne que ça devrait être *nous*.

Je vous remercie d'avance pour votre aide.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour les corrections!

Comment: Très bon article by the way. Le texte complet est disponible sur l'[EUDML](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm2/fm2114.pdf)

Comment: Ça n'est pas OCR; c'est une image du texte.  L'OCR serait texte analysé pour les ordinateurs !

Comment: In English - the what we are calling pure proofs of existence. ci-dites, ci=in this text, dites=called or: the pure proofs of existence in this paper

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ça fait deux questions, je commence par la plus facile :

Oui, *nons* est une erreur d'OCR ou une coquille (typo). Ce devrait être *nous*.

Pour la deuxième, *les si dites* est en fait probablement *les ci-dites*, qui n'est pas une expression courante en français de 2013, elle serait certainement comprise par le public visé (les matheux), mais pas forcément par tout le monde et sonne plutôt désuète et très formelle. Elle signifie « celles que nous appellerons dans la suite ».

Si on veut détailler, *ci* veut dire *ici* et *dites* veut dire *appelées*. Si j'avais à le traduire en anglais, j'en ferais

> *that we will call* pure proof of existence *from now on*.

Comment: _Ci_ plutôt que _si_.  Ça me semble tellement vieux comme usage (hors expressions consacrées qui ont d'ailleurs un trait d'union, comme _ci-après_) qu'il me semble que ce devait déjà être désuet à l'époque où l'article a été écrit; il est naturellement possible que _ci dites_ soit une expression qui ait survécu plus longtemps que l'usage général, mais pas jusque nos jours.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, Evpok. Vous avez m'aidé beaucoup, maintenant je comprends cette phrase. // @Unfrancophone Est-ce que vous dites que "si" et "ci" sont synonymes en Français vieux?

Comment: Non.  _Ci_ est un synonyme vieux de _ici_.  _Si_ a une série d'emplois mais n'est jamais synonyme de _ici_.  Pour que l'orthographe _si_ soit correcte, il faudrait qu'il soit un adverbe d'intensité, ce qui n'a guère de sens pour _dites_; on peut imaginer d'il manque un autre adverbe (_si souvent dites_ p.e.) mais le mot manquant ne peut être un problème d'OCR, ce qui est possible pour la substitution de _si_ à la place de _ci_ (et même l'absence de trait d'union qui est me semble-t'il systématique dans les expressions utilisant _ci_ ayant survécu jusqu'à nous).

Comment: @Unfrancophone Ah, indeed.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Merci beaucoup. Donc je suppose que l'original était "...-- les ci-dites ...".

Comment: En lire le paragraphe de l'article encore une fois, le "ci-dites" sonne exactement comme "so called". Peut-être c'est aussi une possibilité pour le traduire.

Comment: OCR? Il me semble plutôt qu'il s'agisse d'un document scanné, non? Ceci dit... il me semble aussi que le mot "démonstration" devrait être au pluriel, non? "ci-dites pures démonstrations d’existence"

Comment: L'article tout entier contient plusieurs tournures, que j'hésite à qualifier de maladresses car le mot serait un peu fort, qui me semblent dûes au fait que le français n'était pas la langue maternelle de l'auteur. Je pense notamment aux doubles négations telles que "parfois nous ne savons pas distinguer dans cette classe aucun objet particulier" (il en existe plusieurs exemples). Peut-être faut-il considérer le "si dites pures" comme une telle tournure (peut-être transposée du polonais ou du russe) ?

Comment: @lmsteffan Le *aucun* dans ce cas est sûrement est un emploi vieilli plus qu'incorrect, voir http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aucun sens A

Answer (score 2):

Ce n'est ni vieilli, ni incorrect. Mais du jargon mathématique (relativement) courant.

> ci-dites = ici-dites = dites dans le contexte qui nous préoccupe ici

En anglais : *the so-called proof of existence* ou *the said proof of existence*.

Sur le fond, Serpinski explique ici que les mathématiciens n'ont pas besoin d'avoir un objet concret sous la main pour dire des choses intéressantes à son sujet. Il suffit d'en connaitre les propriétés et de savoir qu'un objet de la sorte existe. On peut alors commencer à faire des déductions.

Les preuves soit disant dites d'existences [*les ci-dites preuves*] n'exhibent en général pas un objet, mais s'assimilent à des recettes pour construire (en un nombre d'étapes fini ou non) un tel objet. Et encore, en général, on abouti non pas à un objet concret, mais à toute une classe dans lequel il ***suffit*** de choisir un objet quelconque. Or, et c'est là que le bât blesse, l'axiome du choix dans la théorie de Zermelo-Freankel permet d'affirmer l'existence d'un tel objet mais ne donne aucune méthode pour effectuer ce choix.

Seprinski illustre ceci sur les ensembles non mesurables. Une preuve indirecte montre qu'il est certain qu'il existe de tels ensembles. Par ailleurs, personne n'en a jamais trouvé un, pas tellement parce que c'est difficile mais parce que c'est impossible.

Dans le reste de l'article, Serpinski construit une famille non vide d'ensembles de cardinal supérieur à celui du continu. Il suffit alors d'en choisir un, par l'axiome du choix de Zermelo. Si tout le monde sait qu'il est impossible d'exhiber explicitement l'ensemble choisi, personne ne peux nier qu'il en existe un. D'où son introduction sur les théorèmes d'existence.

Conculsion1: ***si dites*** est une typo pour ***ci-dites***.

Conclusion2: Est-ce bien le bon forum ?

Comment: Le bon forum ? Pour la question oui, pour cette réponse pas vraiment…

Comment: ci-dites is not so-called. ci-dites c'est: what are called pure proofs of existence here or in this paper. so-called is: soi-disant

Comment: @Lambie "so-called" is better translated by *prétendu(es)* here, not *soi-disant* which would be [controversial](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/soi-disant-pour-pretendu).

Comment: @jlliagre J'allais du français soi-disant ***vers l'anglais***. Attention à la direction dans laquelle on traduit. Il n'y a pas d'équivalence bi-univoque. Dans ce texte, ci-dites (les ci-dites preuves) n'est absolumment pas so-called. Un point, c'est tout. Ce soi-disant  président = the so-called president. D'ailleurs, ce pauvre con "T" l'a dit (au sujet d'un juge Fédérale aux Etat-Unis): "The so-called judge": Ce soi-disant juge.....:)

Comment: Ah oui, les *pures démonstrations* ne sont ni prétendues, ni « soi-disantes »... J'avais lu trop vite. Sorry.