# Où « de la sorte » est-il employé adjectivement etc. ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, adjectifs, locutions, régionalismes

On connaît une [*sorte*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sorte/0) de chose soit une *catégorie*, une *espèce*, un *genre* etc. De plus on connaît la locution adverbiale « [de la sorte](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_la_sorte) » signifiant « de cette manière(-là) » ou « ainsi ». Qu'en est-il de l'emploi adjectival ?

> Après un premier incident de la sorte survenu vers la fin du mois de
> mai, l’individu faisait l’objet d’une interdiction de conduite
> nationale, confirme la Sûreté du Québec. ([Radio-Canada.ca](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/1806212/quadriporteur-route-interdit-aine-centre-du-quebec))
>
> [...] il s’agit seulement d’une idée qui m’a traversé l’esprit, il
> m’arrive parfois de laisser vagabonder mes pensées dans des futilités
> de la sorte et après, malheureusement, je [...] ([Jean-Lou
> Frenette](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46704/quelle-serait-une-fa%C3%A7on-plus-%C3%A9l%C3%A9gante-de-formuler-pour-ce-que-cet-individu-ho#comment93451_46706))

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sup. A. Rey, Robert, 2011) nous explique que :

> ***De la sorte*** loc. adv. « de cette manière » [1545], toujours usuel, s'est employé adjectivement pour qualifier une chose (*chose de la
> sorte* « telle » [1640], emploi encore vivant régionalement) [...]

Je suis un locuteur natif du français du Québec et je reconnais l'emploi (ou un emploi de la sorte) dans les deux exemples et le trouve usuel (peut-être plus à l'oral, je ne sais pas). J'associe cet emploi contemporain dans les deux exemples à celui que décrit le DHLF.

---

- L'emploi dans les deux exemples est-il identique et correspond-il à
  celui présenté au DHLF ; est-ce un emprunt à la langue anglaise ?
- Dans quelle(s) région(s) de la francophonie cet emploi est-il encore
  vivant ?
- L'emploi s'analyse-t-il comme *tel(les) incident/futilités* ou comme
  *tel genre de...* ou est-ce essentiellement la même chose ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En recherchant les occurrences de *de la sorte* sur FSE, j'ai trouvé [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6022) :

> Il suffit d'en connaitre les propriétés et de savoir qu'un objet de la sorte existe.

Il s'agit bien d'un emploi adjectival. Son auteur n'est pas québécois  mais [suisse ayant fait des études en France](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30275/dans-la-vraie-vie/30325#comment61461_30325).

L'expression ni ne me surprend, ni ne pose un quelconque problème de compréhension. C'est aussi le cas des phrases de Radio Canada et de JL Frenette.

Voici un autre exemple écrit par [Carine Palmi](https://www.linkedin.com/in/carine-palmi-b050b668/?originalSubdomain=fr), journaliste à *La Provence* et originaire de cette même région :

> [Oui mais voilà, les associations environnementales ne sont pas vraiment en faveur d'une entreprise de la sorte.](https://www.laprovence.com/article/edition-aix-pays-daix/6136882/le-bois-pour-remplacer-le-charbon.html)

- Il s'agit bien de l'usage présenté au DHLF.
- On peut donc au moins ajouter la Suisse romande et la Provence au Québec.
- J'ai l'impression que c'est la même chose. Comme synonymes, je proposerais : "un incident *similaire, de même nature*" et "des futilités *du même goût, du même acabit*".

Answer (score -2):

Il peut être vérifié dans la recherche Google « [de la sorte](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22de%20la%20sorte%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » que presque tous les cas se réduisent au syntagme défini ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sorte)).

> 1. Loc. adv.
>    − De la sorte. De cette manière. Synon. ainsi.Ayant parlé de la sorte en langue d'oc, ce naïf orateur embrassa le superbe et lui mit sur la tête une guirlande d'argent fleuronnée d'or (Cladel, Ompdrailles, 1879, p. 186).

En emploi de modification de nom le mot « sorte » a son sens usuel, mais se trouve en comparaison rarement.

> ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Journal_de_la_Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_de_statistique_d/qeocAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22de+la+sorte%22&dq=%22de+la+sorte%22&printsec=frontcover)) Quoi qu'il en soit , à partir de là , la recherche d'un bon schéma justificatif peut conduire soit à la conclusion que l'agrégat supposé exister en soi n'existe pas ou , plutôt , n'est pas de la sorte idéale qu'on imaginait , soit , surtout , conduire à ...

On trouve d'ailleurs dans le *Lexique de la langue de Molière comparée à celle des écrivains de son temps*", un ouvrage qui date de 1895, qu'à la différence des autres écrivains il substituait un article défini à la place d'un démonstratif.

> ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Lexique_de_la_langue_de_Moli%C3%A8re_compar/-H1nbAktV_YC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22de+la+sorte%22&pg=PA142&printsec=frontcover)) p. 141 7° *Article indéfini le, la, les pour adjectif démonstratif ce, cet, cette.* [« de la sorte » au lieu de « de cette sorte »]

Ceci montre que l'usage de l'article indéfini à valeur démonstrative n'existe que chez Molière ; en fait l'usage non démonstratif de l'article pour donner le syntagme défini n'est pas interrompu et se prolonge à travers les siècles qui vont suivre.

Comme il y a peu de chance qu' au Québec cet usage ait été influencé par Molière au 17éme siècle, il est strictement Québécois.

Étant donnée,  en anglais, la pratique  solidement établie  d'attribuer une valeur démonstrative à l'article et la promiscuité qui caractérise le français et l'anglais dans le nouveau monde, on peut supposer que « l'inspiration  » vient de l'anglais. Cependant, je ne peux rien trouver, vu mes moyens limités, qui permette d'assurer cela en tant que fait.

Comment: Mais qui est donc ce *Molière* dont le français semble corrompu par un *mauvais anglicisme* ? Heureusement que quasiment personne n'a jamais lu ou vu jouer ses obscures œuvres. Que dirait-on s'il avait connu le succès, voire même donné son surnom au français...

Comment: @jlliagre (Tiré de l'article en référence) 1/
Scapin,  il faut faire quelque chose pour lui. Le moyen, après une avanie de la sorte ! 2/
Monsieur de la Rapière, un homme de la sorte Doit être regretté. // Il n'est pas question d'adjectif mais d'un complément prépositionnel introduit par « de ».

Comment: Quelle l'expression anglaise dont s’inspirerait cet usage ?

Comment: @LPH [adjectival](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/adjectival): **qui fait fonction d'adjectif**.

Comment: @XouDo I s'agit non d'une expression mais d'une valeur de l'article défini "the" qui est assez souvent donnée à cet article en anglais ; l'article n'a plus alors sa valeur normale  d'article mais il prend celle de démonstratif ("this", "that" et "the" ont une origine commune en anglais, d'où ce rapprochement). ex. :  /— There is a man in the yard and he is asking for work. — tell the man there is no work./ En français : /— Il y a un homme dans la cour et il demande du travail. — Dites à **cet** homme qu'il n'y a pas de travail./ (On ne dit pas normalement « Dites à **l**'homme qu'il n'y… ».

Comment: @jlliagre Je sais bien que ce mot signifie « de la nature de l'adjectif », mais je ne crois que qu'une expression adjectivale ait quelque sens que ce soit dans ce cas précis de remplacer « de la sorte ».

Comment: @LPH Ce que je crois surtout, c'est que ta dernière phrase est du charabia. Comment peux-tu te poser en puriste de la langue de Molière (ou pas) tout en la violentant de la sorte ?

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne me pose en rien du tout : ce n'est pas moi qui le dit, Molière n'a pas été suivi, c'est cet article qui le dit. Trêve de fariboles.

Comment: @LPH Un "article" de 1895 affirme que c'est Molière qui a dicté en octobre 2020 les mots d'une journaliste de *La Provence* ?